# Trouble writing and compiling element in angular directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a common control that generates an input based on the object passed to it.  I have just added bootstrap prefix and suffix, which work fine.

I also want to add a suffix list, if available.  This will allow the user to change the unit  of the input, i.e.
Standing Charge could be pence per day ('p/day') up to GBP per year ('£/year').  Instead of having 4 optional inputs I just want to have the dropdown on the suffix.

So I find out if there is a suffix:

```
if (scope.model.iSuffix) {
```

and then if it's an array

```
if ($.isArray(scope.model.iSuffix)) {
```

then I mock up the control and append it all where it needs to be

```
var suffixGrp = $('<div>');
suffixGrp.attr("class", "input-group-btn");

scope.suffix = scope.model.iSuffix[0];

var suffixBtn = $('<button>');
suffixBtn.attr("type", "button");
suffixBtn.attr("class", "btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle");
suffixBtn.attr("data-toggle", "dropdown");
suffixBtn.attr("aria-haspopup", "true");
suffixBtn.attr("aria-expanded", "false");
suffixBtn.text('{{suffix}}');

suffixGrp.append(suffixBtn);

var suffixOpts = $('<div>');
suffixOpts.attr("class", "dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right")

var suffixItem = $('<a>');
suffixItem.attr("class", "dropdown-item");
suffixItem.attr("href", "#");
suffixItem.attr("ng-repeat", "suff in model.iSuffix");
suffixItem.attr("ng-click", "suffix = suff");
suffixItem.text('{{suff}}');

suffixOpts.append(suffixItem);

suffixGrp.append(suffixOpts);

inputGroup.append(suffixGrp);
```

Ok, cool.  I just need to compile and it should be done:

```
$compile(inputGroup)(scope);
```

Now the suffix appears where it should and the dropdown shows on click etc, etc

Only issue is that the item ng-click does nothing.  I only want it to update 'scope.suffix'

It looks as though it has interpolated the value of 'suff' as pure text.

I tried to change it:

```
<!-- suffixItem.text('{{suff}}'); -->
suffixItem.html('{{suff}}');
```

but no joy.  Am I missing something? maybe my 'suffix = suff' is the issue?

Thanks
Andy

PS:
I'll set up the jsfiddle to show you what I mean.  Will post when ready

**EDIT:**
Here is the jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/akrd77d3/8/

Note that I changes the ng-click event to an alert, which does not fire.
I could just pit it with a jQuery event, but Should I need to?

Ta ^_^

Comment: `ng-click="alert()"` will execute an alert function on the isolate scope. Add a `scope.alert` function in your directive and you will see it gets executed. Can you add a full example with the dropdown and the real problem?

Comment: Here's what I have: http://plnkr.co/edit/xxx2As1wHQ90CVEL12k0

Comment: `ng-click` only executes functions on scope. It does not execute global functions such as `alert`.

Comment: ah - ok.  The Plunker version I posted is changed back to 
                        suffixItem.attr("ng-click", "suffix = suff");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a scoping issue because of your ng-repeat. Try this in your original code:

```
suffixItem.text("{{suff+':'+suffix}}");
```

and then click on the various elements; you'll see what's happening. When you make the assignment to 'suffix' in the 'ng-click', it becomes part of the **child** scope of the repeated item instance (and no longer the same 'suffix' that is part of the scope of the parent item).

This is another reason to use the 'controllerAs' syntax; it reduces the chance of these sorts of gotchas.

Comment: Here is the RecipeNode directive: http://plnkr.co/edit/xxx2As1wHQ90CVEL12k0
I'm having a couple of issues getting it loaded in Plunker, but at least you can see all the code.
Could you let me know how I can utilize the "controllerAs" to fix the issue
I'm still a bit hazy on where the child scope is branching off
Thanks ^_^

Comment: I ended up updating suffix via a function.  Had no idea ng-repeat had it's own scope :S